# Compose ranges in 2D list

Tags: python, list, range, 2d

Given a sorted integer list in Python that does not contain any duplicates,  I want to compose a 2D list which contain the ranges (with an increment of 1) based on that list. So for example: `x = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 9]`, I want the result to be:
`[[-1, 0, 1, 2], [6, 7], [9]]` or
`y = [4, 5, 7, 12, 15, 16]` should result in `[[4,5], [7], [12], [15,16]]`

Answer (score 0):

try using `numpy`:

```
from numpy import diff, where, split
result= split(x, where(diff(x)>1)[0]+1 )
print(list(map(list, result)))
```

---

```
[[-1, 0, 1, 2], [6, 7], [9]]
```

**OR** you can use `more_itertools`:

```
import more_itertools as mit
print([list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(x)])
```

**OR**

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

print([list(map(itemgetter(1), group)) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(x), lambda i: i[0] - i[1])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using native python only:

```py
def foo(x):
    head, *tail = x
    result = [[head]]
    for j in tail:
        if j == result[-1][-1]+1:
            result[-1].append(j)
        else:
            result.append([j])
    return result
```